# How to call external Rest API from WSO2 EI Studio?

Tags: database, rest, api, wso2, wso2-esb

We have a requirement to call the external rest API from WSO2. So 
I have create a spring boot application separately which stores the data into postgres db.This all are external resource, how can I call this service from WSO2 ? All I found on the web is that we can create rest api in WSO2 itself. but my requirement do not matches to that. Please share the all procedure which I need to do in WSO2. 
Thanks in advance
[I have attached the image now which is the full use case](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VzBTX.png)

AddPerson.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<endpoint name="AddPerson" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
    <http method="post" uri-template="http://localhost:8080/wsoPOCApp/createPerson"/>
</endpoint>
```

This is the endPoint I created but it is not responding when I am hitting it I through curl command 
I am using below command for curl

```
curl -X POST -H 'Accept: application/json'  -H 'Content-Type: application/json' --data "@person-payload.json" http://192.168.0.109:8280/wsoPOCApp/createPerson
```

I also tried to hit this using Postman but it is giving me 404

```
C:\Users\User>curl -X POST -H 'Accept: application/json'  -H 'Content-Type: application/json' --data "@person-payload.json" http://192.168.0.109:8280/wsoPOCApp/createPerson
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: application
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: application
```

[This is the image from management console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v75PF.png)

Comment: Are you trying to call an endpoint directly from outside ? As far as I know, WSO2 EI endpoint can be called only inside an API or Proxy Service code created in the EI. So please let me know if you have created any API or Proxy and trying to call the endpoint through call or send mediator.

Comment: I have created API end point,which I can see in management console and can see it s end point but when I am hitting it, it is giving me 404

Comment: So I can't hit an endpoint ? But I can hit that api end point right or that also I can't do ?

Comment: You have to create an API, which calls that end point. Then if you call the API , the API calls the endpoint.

Comment: Yes prabakaran, I have created an api and I am hitting this API URL only but I am still stuck.

Comment: In the question I have attached the image of that api in management console, but i am not able to hit that, also documentations says to do curl, I am doing from command prompt, do I need to use any other CLI ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create an HTTP Endpoint, configure the HTTP Method, provide the URI, save it.

In your code, you to use a Call/Send mediator, and have to specify the endpoint you have created above inside the Call/Send mediator.

If you already have a WSO2 EI code, please update your question, so that I can provide the exact answer.

[HTTP Endpoint](https://docs.wso2.com/display/EI6xx/HTTP+Endpoint)

Comment: Hi Prabakaran, i have updated the question, please check and suggest. TIA

Comment: It's working now, thanks for the help, I actually already did whatever you said but it was not working so I tried again the same step and it worked somehow.